# Javascript Function syntax in plain English

Tags: syntax

I'm a part-time English teacher and I want to teach students basic programming so I try to rewrite syntax into plain English for them to understand more easily.

So I rewrite Javascript:

```
function functionName(a, b, c) {
  // actual function
  return a + b + c
};
functionName(1,2,3);
```

as plain English:

```
formula formulaName(input1, input2, input3) {
  // actual formula
  run input1 + input2 + input3
};

// without the formula keyword it means execute
// with the formula keyword it means define:

formulaName(1,2,3); 

// formula that assigns 1,2,3 as input1, input2, input3, then adds them to get the output when executed
```

Is my english translation correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd reckon to call it `function` instead of `formula`. A function can do more things than a formula itself. A formula is something applied on one or more expressions whereas a function can contain more than one formula, even an output of a formula can be used as an input for another formula within the same function. Also, the keyword `execute` make more sense than `run`. You can also use the keyword `statement` to refer each expression. There is nothing wrong as long as syntactical pseudo code is correct.